# Authentication using express and graphql

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am new to GraphQL and seeking your help. Right now, We have React application which will talk to REST API which is developed in .NET Core. Now, we are going to introduce GraphQL between Client and REST API server.

I could not consume .NET REST API in GraphQL (resolver) using either fetch API or AXIOS because of Windows authentication. .NET Core is protected by Windows authentication with help of NTLM. What needs to be done to make API from GraphQL.

Do we need to captured Windows authenticated user information in GraphQL and pass to .Net Core API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried httpntlm module?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpntlm

Comment: The library requires to pass username and password to authenticate. But I dont want the user to enter if they are connected in the same network and already logged in.